# how to do server authentication to download plist files from a password protected directory in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to access some plist files from a remote server, which are in a password protected directory. In case of not using a password to access the directory, i use the simple code and it works:

```
NSString *query = @"http://www.sante.com/FFFF/privat/updateDates.plist";

NSURL *urlDates = [NSURL URLWithString:[query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; 
NSDictionary *datesUrl = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:urlDates];
```

But in case of password protected directory, does it exist a way to treat it in xcode (without using NSUrlCOnnection, xmlparser because i don't want to parse the file while i can access directly by using dictionaryWithContentsOfURL)?

Edit: The point is that i just want to write some code to access/download the plist files (which are in a password protected directory of server) from the webserver to ios device. But i don't know how to. In case of not using password for accessing server directory, my above code works very well, but i need to access them in secured mode, and i just need to validate the webserver directory password programatically (hard coded).

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. XCode is a development tool, are you trying to open a file from within the XCode environment, or are you trying to write code to download the file at runtime on an ios device? If you clarify what you are trying to do, you may get more assistance. Also, you might want to research dictionaryWithContentsOfURL a little more - the URL doesn't have to be a webserver.

Comment: You should be able to edit or comment on your own question. Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to deal with customising the download process by supporting authentication, then you *need* to stop using `dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:` and start using `NSConnection` because `NSConnection` *is* the API for customising URL downloads. Particularly, look at the delegate method `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` which is where you hook in to the authentication procedure.

You don't need to use an XML parser, because you have no need to parse the downloaded contents. Hand the data off to `NSPropertyListSerialization` once you've downloaded them and that can return an `NSDictionary` instance to you.